# I am the actual inventor for a patent. What can I do about not being recorded as the inventor?

Tags: inventorship, us20020144536

I am the actual inventor for patent no. US20020144536.  The listed inventors are a fraud.  I have all the original drawings, designs, development pictures, and testing reports.  What can I do about not being recorded as the inventor?

Answer (score 1):

If you bring this question to an attorney, you will most likely be asked what you wish to accomplish.

If you are seeking compensation, the attorney might ask whether you could show any damages or prove that you were intentionally excluded as an inventor.  The ability of the patentee to pay any settlement or judgment also sounds like a relevant consideration.  While failure to pay the maintenance fee on the patent is not conclusive of this, it may suggest a lack of interest in the patent.

If you are seeking only to have your name included, then you might want to ask how much it will cost you.  You may also want to question how the Patent Office will reflect any change if you are successful.  A certificate of correction may not be worth it to you if you have to pay for the filings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Scott, for better or worse, the application you cite did issue as as U.S. Patent US6598457 and then expired in 2011 for non-payment of maintenance fees.

From USPTO Public PAIR database

> Application Number:    09/826,555
>
> Filing or 371 (c) Date: 04-05-2001
>
> Status:  Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362
>
> Status Date:     08-29-2011

Although I am a registered patent agent, I am not an attorney. I imagine you may have some case against whomever has wronged you.